# Filter Exact Match with Grep

Tags: regex, bash, unix, grep

I have been using `grep -w` extensively but recently I noticed that it is not solving my problem.

Let say I have a file with the following contents:

```
$  cat Log.txt
aaa xxx zzz 
bbb xxx aa
cccaaa yy aa
scn-aaa
```

I want to filter all rows which have the word "aaa" exactly match. That means the words "cccaaa" and "scn-aaa" should not come out.

I tried with `grep -w` but no luck

```
$ grep -w "aaa" Log.txt
aaa xxx zzz
scn-aaa

$ grep -w "\<aaa\>" Log.txt
aaa xxx zzz
scn-aaa
```

I also tried `-Fx` but did not help.

Please let me know how I can achieve this with `grep` command.

Note: Each line might have multiple columns which is not fixed.

Answer (score 3):

`grep -w` counts '-' as beginning a word boundary, which is why it is catching scn-aaa. In short, you want to do what -w does, but with a different definition of what constitutes a valid word character.

For grep, a word character is `[_[:alnum:]]`, i.e. any letter or number or the underscore character. So we can roll our own grep -w like match by:

```
grep -E '(^|[^[:alnum:]_-])aaa($|[^[:alnum:]_-])'
```

That is, match aaa when preceded by and followed by the beginning or end of the string, or a non-word character, where we count '-' also as being a word character.

Comment: +1 This will still output the `cccaaa` line because of it containing `aaa` though but I'm inclined to think that that's an error in OP's question.

Comment: @halfflat Thanks for this one. I have 2 queries: 1)But if I have no idea which all special characters are been used (like - in this case) then how can I use it. 2) Also I wanted to know if I set i = aaa , how can I use ${i} in the command. It did not work that way

Comment: I was also able to use $i by working with the quotes. But I still don't know how to handle the situation if I am not aware as to what all special characters have been used in the words.

Comment: At some point you will need to decide what characters should count as separators, and what characters count as words. If it's easier to decide what does count as a word character, then this approach is appropriate: you add more characters to the negative `[^[:album:]_-]` matches. If, on the other hand, it is easier to specify what counts as a separator, then you would use a positive match in the boundary checks, e.g. `grep -E '(^|[[:blank:],;])aaa($|[[:blank:],;)'`

Answer (score 1):

Can also be done with `awk`

```
awk -F"[^[:alnum:]_-]" '{f=0;for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i=="aaa") f=1}f' file
aaa xxx zzz
cccaaa yy aaa
```

Here we set that field separator is not any alpha, numeric nor `_` and `-`.
Then test every field, one by one.  If one hit is found, print the line.

---

For some reason, even if we set correct separators, word boundary fails in `awk`, so do not use this:

```
awk -F"[^[:alnum:]_-]" '/\<aaa\>/' file
aaa xxx zzz
cccaaa yy aaa
scn-aaa
```

Answer (score 1):

I used many of the suggestions but what worked BEST for me is the following command:

```
grep -E '(^|\s)'<PATTERN>'($|\s)' <FILENAME>
```

Below is an example:

```
$ cat Log.txt
aaa xxx zzz
bbb xxx aa
cccaaa yy aa
scn-aaa

$ i=aaa

$ grep -E '(^|\s)'${i}'($|\s)' Log.txt
aaa xxx zzz
```

Thanks everyone for your suggestions :-)

Comment: Just be aware that this won't match things like `(aaa)` or `aaa, bbb`. As long as your data doesn't have that sort of thing you're probably OK.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
grep -P '(?<!\w-)(aaa)(?![\w-])'
```

it matches `aaa` that are not followed or preceded by one of `a-zA-Z0-9` or a `-`.

- `?<!` is a negative lookbehind - makes sure that `aaa` is *not preceded* by `\w-`
- `?!` is a negative lookahead - makes sure that `aaa` is *not followed* bye `\w-`